# Incomplete circle with line in the middle

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

How can I achieve this shape with CSS:
[image: Incomplete circle with line in the middle]

Ideally, I'd like a background shadow effect too.

Comment: That's not how this works.

Comment: You should check out SVG instead

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to your issue? Did the answers help?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with CSS but it realy isn't the best way to make it. It will need to add unsemantic markup, and probably a lot of CSS.
If you don't want to use an image, I would suggest to use an [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) it is much better to control shapes like the one you are trying to achieve.

**With SVG:**

I made this quick example using a [path element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) with [arc commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs) :

```css
svg{
  display:block;
  width:30%; height:auto;
}
body{background:url('http://i.imgur.com/qi5FGET.jpg');background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <path d="M4.5 1 A4.05 4.05 0 0 0 4.5 9z M8.4 3 A4.05 4.05 0 0 0 5.5 1 V9 A4.05 4.05 0 0 0 8.4 7" 
        stroke-width="0.8" fill="transparent" stroke="#000"/>
</svg>
```

**With CSS :**

I also made this CSS example with a possible approach if you really want to go with CSS. It uses only one div and two pseudo elements. The lines are made with borders and border-radius  :

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div:before,div:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  width: 48%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 10px solid #000;
}
div:before {
  border-radius: 900px 0 0 900px;
}
div:after {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 35px 35px 0;
  border-right-color:transparent;  
}
body{background:url('http://i.imgur.com/qi5FGET.jpg');background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One CSs posibility

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid 10px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 85px, black 85px, black 115px, transparent 115px);
  position: relative;
}

.test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another CSS alternative which just uses a single pseudo element to create the extra side of the shape.

The `after` creates the extra curve with a partially transparent border (the right side).

```css
body {
  background: skyblue;
}
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 75px 0px 0px 75px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  top: -10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0px 39px 39px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```